# Why doesn't the Typescript compiler infer this filter typeguard?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to filter out undefined values from an array, but cannot get the compiler to infer the result type properly. I know I could just use a type assertion, but would rather understand how to properly type my callback to achieve this result.

```typescript
const isDefinedNum = (x: number | undefined, _i: number, _a: ReadonlyArray<number | undefined>): x is number => x !== undefined;
const a: (number | undefined)[] = [1, undefined, 2, undefined];
const b = a.filter(isDefinedNum);
```

In the above, `b` is type as `(number | undefined)[]`. I'm trying to get the compiler to unify the call with the following type from `lib.d.ts`:

```
filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (this: void, value: T, index: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => value is S): S[];
```

Comment: Your code in playgroundis showing `b` to be of type `number[]`

Comment: @NitzanTomer I got the same until I turned on `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: Huh that's very strange. I was testing it out in playground before, but now that I try it again, you're right. I must be going crazy...

Comment: You're not crazy. `strictNullChecks` is turned off in playground by default.

Comment: Ok. not I get the same. But looking at the signatures of the [Array.filter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1263) methods it's quite clear that you always get back the same type of array. Because it always returns `T[]`.

Comment: Aha! The annotation I included above is actually for `ReadonlyArray`, whereas plain-old `Array` has [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10916) pending. I am not crazy after all :)

Comment: Seems like an open issue with the compiler: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7657

Comment: Can this issue be closed?  Or do you still want an answer?

Comment: Well, I got the answer in these comments already. I suppose that means it can be closed